# Download a dependency from a specific repository in Maven

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I know this question has been asked many times, but I still cannot find a solution. I have two nexus repository and I have defined two mirrors in settings.xml like this:

```
    <mirrors>    
    <mirror>
      <id>nexus_a</id>
      <mirrorOf>nexus_a,nexus_b</mirrorOf>
      <url>https://***</url>
    </mirror>
    <mirror>
      <id>nexus_b</id>
      <mirrorOf>nexus_b</mirrorOf>
      <url>https://***</url>
    </mirror>
    </mirrors>
```

Then I have the two repositories:

```
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>nexus_a</id>
                <url>https://nexus-a</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>nexus_b</id>
                <url>https://nexus-b</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>                 
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
```

Then in my pom I have a list of dependencies, one of these should be downloaded from nexus_a, the other from nexus_b.
Also in my pom I have the two repositories like before.

Thanks to anyone answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your mirror definitions are kind of contradictory and I don't understand their purpose.

Secondly, you cannot choose for a dependency where it should be downloaded from. But I also see no important reason for that. If you define both repositories, Maven will just look in the first one, and if it does not find anything, it will look in the second one. So except for performance, I see no disadvantage.

Comment: but also if I set the two mirrors to only nexus_a and nexus_b it doesnt work. It always look only in the second repository, nexus_b

Comment: I would remove all the mirror configuration. It does not look like you need mirrors at all.